# What does the error "the exec task needs a command to execute" mean?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, compiler-construction

When compiling a project in Visual Studio, the error message "the exec task needs a command to execute"  appears, with no line number.  What does this error mean?

(Apologies for asking and answering my own question; I just found an answer as I was writing this.  Have made it community wiki, so as not to offend.)

Comment: Don't apologize, you just saved me a lot of digging!

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Ken Egozi has [found an answer](http://www.kenegozi.com/blog/2007/05/24/the-quotexecquot-task-needs-a-command-to-execute-the-poor-thing.aspx).

The message is caused by stray newline characters in pre or post build commands.

Comment: Thanks. You saved my time.

Comment: Thanks saved my time.

Comment: Problem and solution still valid for Visual Studio 2017

Comment: Thanks you also save my time. I edited "post build" event and left an empty line there.. Still valid for Visual Studio 2022.

Answer (score 11):

That link is no longer good.
[HERE](http://kenegozi.com/blog/2007/05/24/the-quotexecquot-task-needs-a-command-to-execute-the-poor-thing) is a new link.

And here is a pertinent quote from the blog:
"After pooling out a few hairs, I remembers that I recently have edited the pre-build actions for this project.
Looking this up, I found that I left a spare newline at the end of the pre-build script. So VS2005 sent msbuild an order to run an empty command."